# Excel automatically unselects the popup box when I use the column width shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

When I use the keyboard shortcut to change column width (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>), a popup box comes up to type in the column width size.

Generally speaking, immediately after typing the shortcut, the popup box is automatically *selected*, and you should be able to key in the column width.

For my Excel, the popup box is automatically *deselected*. So I need to mouse over and click on the box before I can key in the column width. This is slow and somewhat defeats the purpose of the shortcut.

Any reason the popup box automatically deselects? Any fix would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to File > Account > Product Informtaion, check the version name of your Office. Such as Office 2019, Microsoft 365 apps. Then click About Excel, check the version number.

I suggest you update Office for a test. As different versions of Office may have different methods to get updates.

- If you see "Update Options" under Product Information, you may click
  it choose "Update Now".
- If there is no "Update Options" button under Product Information, you
  may installed the updates from "[Latest updates for versions of
  Office that use Windows Installer (MSI)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/office-updates-msi)".

Or you may try to [repair Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) from Contral Panel.